# why does this log the old value and not the new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

```
const [title,setTitle] = useState(""); 
const titleHandler=e => {
setTitle(e.target.value) 
console.log(title) 
}
```

Why does this code log the old value of title and not the new one. I'm new to js and react please can anyone explain this to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happend because when you call `setTitle` it doesn't update the state instantaneously but it trigger a rerender of the component with the updated state

if you do

```
const [title,setTitle] = useState(""); 
const titleHandler=e => {
setTitle(e.target.value) 
console.log('updating title') 
}  

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('title updated', title)
}, [title])
```

you can see for yourself